# Why does this message appear when I try to install Node.js?

Tags: node.js

I'm trying to install Node.js and this message occurs every time. I already have Node.js installed, but I am trying to install it again to use Angular. I am unable to install due to below error. Can someone can help me?

The alternative was to install as administrator, but this option doesn't show for me.

[image]